# toolbar hide behind the navigation image

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am creating one app in which i have to use navigation image.
without navigation image i can see the toolbar option perfectly

navigation bar without image at app start up-home screen
[image: navigation bar without image at app start up-home screen]

navigation image after navigate to second page
[image: navigation image after navigate to second page]

now i am adding an image in my navigation bar using

```
UIImageView *topBar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 45)];
topBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_cell.png"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:topBar];
```

now the navigation bar look like at home screen perfect

[image: navigation image after adding image]

but in second page the toolbar option hidden [image: hidden toolbar]

so how can i show toolbar above the image in navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:topBar belowSubview:navigationBar];
```

It will insert your view under your navigation bar.

A second option is to use this code after yours:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar bringSubviewToFront: topBar]
```

that will put your top bar at the top of the view stack.

Answer (score 0):

finally lots of work i found the solution first i have added image in `viewWillAppear` method then after i added my toolbar in `viewDidAppear` method just like below code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
//    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = TRUE;


///// Edit Hiren

UIImageView *topBar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 45)];
topBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top-bar.png"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:topBar];


}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 685, 44);
    // [toolbar sizeToFit];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar];
    //    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];

}
```